# At what parameters is following $NP$-hard?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness, parameterized-complexity, subset-sum

Problem Instances at given $\alpha>0$.

$(1)$ Given $a_1,\dots,a_{n^\alpha}\in\Bbb Z$ with $|a_i|\in(2^{n-1},2^n-1)$ is there a subset of that sums to $0$?

$(2)$ Given $a_1,\dots,a_{n}\in\Bbb Z$ with $|a_i|\in(2^{n-1},2^n-1)$ is there a subset of size at most $n^\alpha$ that sums to $0$?

At what range of $\alpha$ are these problems $NP$-hard?

Is the problem studied anywhere?

Comment: For both problems, the empty set yields a trivial solution.

Comment: Are you sure you want the $a_i$'s to be reals rather than integers?

Comment: @HuckBennett I think for finite precision it would not have mattered.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1311.3054